# Assign CKEditor To Dynamically Created Text Box Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've a table structure where a **CKEditor** is attached to a table td. Something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="questionDetails">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Question Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
            <th>Answers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="txtQuestionName form-control" name="txtQuestionName" value="" />
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="txtOptions form-control" name="txtOptions" value="" />
                <span class="addOptions">(+)</span> &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="txtAnswers form-control" value="" />
                <span class="addAnswers">(+)</span> &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" class="txtExplanation form-control editor1" name="editor1" />
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**:

```
<script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        //Initialize CKEditor by giving id of text area
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

        //Get each instance of CKEditor
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            //update element
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
        }

  //Add row to the table
   $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        $("#questionDetails").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="txtQuestionName form-control" class="form-control" /></td> <td><input type="text" class="txtOptions form-control" /><span class="addOptions">(+)</span></td> <td><input type="text" class="txtAnswers form-control" /> <span class="addAnswers">(+)</span></td><td><input type="text" class="txtExplanation form-control editor1" name="editor1" /></td> <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger remCF">Remove</a></td> &nbsp;</tr>');
   });
</script>
```

The above code works when the page is loaded by default. But when I try to add more rows to the table dynamically using `jQuery`, that doesn't create or assign the **CKEditor** to that input element. The other input elements are created except the editor. Is there any way I can assign the **CKEditor** to the dynamically created rows in the table and get all the values from it?

Comment: Put `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');` in a function and call it in `$("#btnAdd").click(function () {`

Comment: Well! I tried and got this in the console - **VM151:21 [CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-element-conflict**. Used this in the add event - `function AddEditors() { CKEDITOR.replace('editor1'); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example. You have to make sure to give all editors a unique ID

```
<div>
    <textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
    <button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add CKEditor</button>
</div>

<div id="questionDetails">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //the inital editor
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

    //use an number to make the id's of the new editors unique
    var index = 2;

    //Add row to the table
    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {

        //create the new id
        var newEditor = 'editor' + index;

        //append some html
        $("#questionDetails").append('<textarea id="' + newEditor + '"></textarea>');

        //init the new editor
        CKEDITOR.replace(newEditor);

        //increment
        index++;
    });
</script>
```

If you want to read the contents, simply loop the instances and get the data with `getData()`

```
$("#btnRead").click(function () {
    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        alert(CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData());
    }
});
```

Comment: This just worked fine @VDWWD. Thanks for it, but I like to get all the values from those editors using `jQuery` map declaring a class - `var explanations = $row.find('.txtExplanation').map(function () { return this.value; }).get().join("_");`. This sample didn't work.

Comment: I think you are looking for `CKEDITOR.instances`